# SSIS deployment option missing - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to deploy an SSIS package (visual studio 2015) to our SQL 2016 server. However, the option to deploy is not being displayed. I have already tested it on a previous package as shown below:

[image]

But the other project does not give me the option to do the same. Only to execute the package. It may be worth noting that this project has been upgraded via the wizard from visual studio 2008 to 2015 and was successful.

[image]

Am I missing a configuration?

Comment: Maybe it's still using the package deployment model (rather than the project deployment model)

Comment: Thanks! i converted it to project deployment model and now i get the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into properties and verify that you have selected a deployment target.

Comment: I right clicked the project and changed it from Package to project deployment model. thanks for the help!